# What is the command to find a jar file in a particular folder?

Tags: linux, find

What is the command  to find a jar file in a particular folder?

Say I want to find `log4j.jar` in the /dev directory, what command should I use?

Answer (score 19):

You can use `find`. In your case:

```
find /dev/ -name log4j.jar
```

You can also use wildcards, for example

```
find /dev/ -name \*.jar
```

would find all `.jar` files under `/dev`.

Note that find does the search resursively, i.e. searches all subfolders of `/dev`, too. You can adjust the maximal depth of your search using the `-maxdepth` parameter, see `man find` for more details.

Note also that in your case you should perhaps have `root` permissions because not all subfolders in `/dev` are readable by all users. In a debian/ubuntu system you could just add a `sudo` before the `find` command.

---

If you don't want to search resursively you could just use `ls` for example

```
ls /dev/*jar
```

will list all `jar` files under `/dev`.

Comment: Already used this command but not working

Comment: @Mohini: "not working" is not very descriptive, we can't guess how it is failing for you. Also, having a `.jar` file in `/dev` would be very, very non-conventional. If the above commands don't return anything, it means the file is not there.

Comment: You could try it searching a file you know it is in `/dev`

Comment: i have already downloaded those files from the path and used find command but still find command is not showing the path.

Comment: Is the file really in /dev or ~/dev? In other words, is the file somewhere under your home directory? Using find to search the wrong directory won't return what you expect.

Comment: yeah the file is in /dev subfolders like /dev/lib.